# Create an IO string

Tags: haskell

For some reason getLine is not working in my Jupiter notebook. Is there any way to create artificially an IO string so I can continue with some examples that need that?

I tried something like this:

```
main = do
    foo :: IO String
    foo << "sdf"
```

But didn't work obviously. Any way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: `let foo = return "sdf"` ?

Comment: “create artificially an IO string” is almost certainly _not_ what you want. I think you haven't understood what's the point of monadic actions at all. Explain what problem you're facing that prompted you to define `foo` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Yes sorry may be I didn't explain properly. I'm following a training, which is now in the IO stuff. It has several examples which require getLine, which is not working for me. So I'd like to hardcode a string to replace the failed getLine, so I just input it and continue.

Comment: You don't need `IO` then, just hardcode a `String` constant.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If the tutorial includes doing stuff like `getLine >>= print`, it doesn't seem unreasonable to want some other `IO String` to substitute in its place, rather than figuring out what changes are needed to work with a pure String.

Comment: Please provide the context in which `getLine` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of type `IO String` represents an action that may do some `IO` and produce a `String` if it’s executed (ultimately, from `main`). Normally, `getLine` is such an action that reads a line of text from “standard input” (`stdin`). If you just want to make *your own* action to use instead of `getLine`, you can construct one quite simply using `pure :: (Applicative f) => a -> f a` where `f` is `IO` and `a` is `String` in this case:

```
fakeGetLine :: IO String
fakeGetLine = pure "always the same string"
```

Aside: `pure` is also called `return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a` for historical reasons, but there’s no need to use it, since it’s the same function with a longer name and a slightly more restricted type.

Now, anywhere you would’ve entered `getLine`, you can replace it with `fakeGetLine`, or an expression such as `pure "whatever string you wish to use"`. Likewise, if you  needed a constant `IO Int`, you could use `pure 123` or `pure (123 :: Int)`.

You can’t replace the standard `getLine`, but it is possible to use your own definition with the same *name* of `getLine`, provided that you hide the default one from scope using an `import`…`hiding` declaration:

```
import Prelude hiding (getLine)

getLine :: IO String
getLine = pure "always the same string"
```

Alternatively, you can in fact read from `stdin` in an IPython notebook, as long as you open it with a frontend that supports the “input request” feature, such as [JupyterLab](https://jupyter.org/) or [Deepnote](https://deepnote.com/). To the best of my knowledge, this is *not* currently supported in [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen), [nteract](https://nteract.io/), or [Spyder](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/plugins/notebook.html).

Finally, a method sometimes recommended for this issue in Python, which will *not* work in Haskell, is attempting to replace `stdin` with a different handle. That technique is possible in Python because its `stdin` is a *mutable* variable, while in Haskell, `stdin` (like all variables) is *immutable*.